# Chooser intent android orientation

Tags: android

I'm working with an app, and I'm asking if it's possible to set the orientation of the chooser dialog when an ACTION_SEND intent was send. In particular, I want that the chooser dialog should be in PORTRAIT even if the app is LANDSCAPE. It's possible to set (or maybe force) in some way the orientation? Or it's a system setting that cannon't be modified? Thanks in advice.

Comment: The receiving side has nothing to do with the chooser intent. The chooser intent is invoked by the sender.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm asking if it's possible to set the orientation of the chooser dialog when an ACTION_SEND intent was send

No, sorry. There are tens of thousands of Android device models. The chooser UI varies substantially among them. And, in all cases, the chooser UI is created by Google and/or device manufacturers, and they will handle orientation how they wish to do so.

> It's possible to set (or maybe force) in some way the orientation?

No, sorry.